# Why Javascript functions behave differently on Chrome 77.0.3865.120 and Safari 13.0.2?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I noticed that functions behave differently on Safari and Chrome, is there any reason?

I don't need a solution, I just would understand why this happens and if it is a bug or whatelse. Here's how you can reproduce it.
You'll see different values in Chrome's console and Safari's console.

```
    const foo = 10;
    {

        const foo = 50;

        function logFoo1(){
            console.log(foo)
        }

        const logFoo2 = function(){
            console.log(foo)
        }

        logFoo1();
        logFoo2();

    }
```

On safari logFoo1() will prompt 10, on Chrome 50.

Comment: Somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035056/javascript-object-definition-available-before-code-execution-on-safari

Comment: I think the simple answer, it's a bug with Safari.. bugs happen.  To me this seems like a major bug too.

Comment: @Snow Really interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Kaiido As I said, I didn't need a solution because I alredy found the IIFE one. I was just wondering on why. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Snow's link apparently has the why (I got fooled by jsfiddle autowrapping in onload handler, thinking it was only in the console, but it's actually only in global scope.) Do you mind if we close your question as a duplicate of the one pointed by Snow?

Comment: @Kaiido no it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It does!

Same piece of Javascript code behaves differently in different browsers. Consider the following piece if code:

```
<script>

alert('\v supported ' + (String.fromCharCode(11)== '\v'));

</script>

Output:

IE: false

FF: true

Opera: true

Safari: true
```

The reason behind this is every browser has its own rendering engine.These are examples of browser engines. These engines are nothing but different adaptations of open Web standards

Comment: That isn't the JavaScript the question is asking about.

Comment: OK, I did edit :p I really should stay away from Safari questions :p - maybe you should post an answer to the OP to tell him that "browser console doesn't behave"